# Why is there a Raspberry Pi logo at startup?

Tags: boot

When you start the RPi, a raspberry appears in the top left corner while exciting white text flows across the screen. How does that work? Is it possible to take it away/change it, or make my Desktop Arch PC do the same thing?

Comment: +1 for "exciting white text".  kernel messages are normally rather boring :)

Comment: Also many distributions hide these by default but they can be reenabled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This logo is standard for Linux distributions, however the actual image might be different. To change and/or replace the image, you have to recompile the kernel -- not very easy thing to do, if you are new to all this Linux stuff.

If you need more info, please, refer to "[How to change the Linux penguin boot logo](http://www.articleworld.org/index.php/How_to_change_the_Linux_penguin_boot_logo)" article, that explains everything in great details.

Comment: I don't think I'm going to recompile my kernel just to add a penguin, but I'll think about it if I do anyway. Thanks!